# Limit microphone input frequency programmatically ios iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, microphone

I would like to limit the microphone's *input frequency* for an **iOS Application** I'm developing which is going to run on all versions of iPhone available in market as of 22 March, 2016.

The microphone will only record if a certain frequency *threshold* is reached and won't be recording below that *threshold*.

Any idea on how to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Yes, [here you go](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-On-Programming/dp/0321636848)

Comment: Is it still unresolved problem? If so, I can help.

Comment: @RafałP yes it is.. can you help me?